# не могу реализовать команду в цикле

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Задание таково:
Дан каталог abc и файл 1 с каким-то текстом.Создать в каталоге файлы,названия которых - это последние слова из строк файла 1,а содержимое -первые 3 строки из файла 1.
Я понимаю,что здесь нужен цикл,но мне трудно все склеить в терминале.
PS. эта команда выводит букву 1 раз а должна столько,сколько строк в файле

```
$ for i in {1..`wc -l 1.txt | sed s/[^0-9]//g`}; do echo "b"; done
```

Что я делаю не так? поясните суть этого всего,пожалуйста ,скоро сдавать лабу

---

$ for i in {1..`wc -l 1.txt | sed s/[^0-9]//g`}; do echo "b"; done
 все равно не пашет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Что я делаю не так?

практически всё. потому что вы пытаетесь написать **программу**, а требуется лишь составить вместе «кирпичики», входящие в состав posix-совместимой операционной системы.

- получить нужное количество строк от начала файла можно, например, с помощью программы *head*:

  ```
  $ head -n количество-строк файл
  ```
- организовать цикл по строкам в файле можно, например, так:

  ```
  $ cat файл | while read line; do echo "содержимое строки: $line"; done
  ```
- получить последнее слово (точнее, удалить всё до последнего пробела включительно) из переменной, в [posix-совместимой оболочке](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) можно, например, так:

  ```
  $ line="это длинная строка"; echo ${line##* }
  ```
- записать вывод какой-нибудь команды в файл можно, например, так (можно указать как непосредственно имя файла, так и переменную, содержащую имя):

  ```
  $ команда > файл
  ```

Comment: большинство практически полезного программирования состоит в составлении готовых кирпичиков. Написание shell pipeline это также программирование. В тему [пример](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/12/more-shell-less-egg/). Подробнее в виде книги: [The Unix Programming Environment](https://9p.io/cm/cs/upe/index.html)

Comment: Спасибо. А если в файле 1.txt  10 строк, как мне сразу же создать 10 новых файлов , названия которых-это последние слова строчек 1.txt.
Тут реализуется цикл?
Как склеить цикл с командой создания и записи в файл?

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich, синтаксис оператора *while* posix-совместимых оболочек: `while условие; do команда1; команда2; команда3; done`. см. `$ help while`